# Display logs of a server in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a web portal. I need to show the logs of a server on that portal. the logs are stored in a .txt file. The file keeps on updating with the new logs and I need to show the in the real time.I am using ruby on rails. please help.

Comment: what kind of logs are we talking about?

Comment: server logs..... errors, warnings... etc.

Comment: you can find them in `development.log` or `production.log` based on your environment, what do you want actually?

Comment: Just tail the log based on the environment you are using Eg:- `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: @abhi.... can you please elaborate.

Comment: See the log folder in your application , all types of logs fall in their respective files . For instance , if you are running your app in local then it will update your development.log and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smoother option than constantly updating the page would be to use the Rails 4 Live Streaming functionality, which would keep a connection open and send data as it comes in. Details are nicely outlined here: http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/

You would probably want to get a text box on the page to connect via AJAX after page load, and write the output from a live streaming controller action into the HTML as it arrives.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
<%= render :file => '/tmp/development.log' %>
```

and keep updating page.